# Only one of two partitions on SD card is recognized

Tags: partitioning, sd-card

I split my SD card into 2 partitions. When I use usb-card-reader to read my sd card, only the one partition shows up on the screen, and the other doesn't. I have run the command `sudo fdisk -l` and the result is the same -- only one partition is recognized. But I believe both partitions of my sd card work, because I can boot my single-board computer with the sd card and run some of the programs which are inside that "unreadable" partition.

How can I access both partitions of my sd card?

Comment: Can you check, if you see more than one partition with the partition manager `gparted` (you'd need to install it, as it's not part of the default installation)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have already used gparted to check the sd card, and there's also only one partition is appeared.

Comment: Can you post the output of `sudo fdisk -lu` and `sudo blkid`? What do you expect to find in the way of partitions? (How large, what filesystem, etc)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Testdisk** to fix partition table and recover missing partitions. To install Testdisk :

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

To use it :

```
sudo testdisk
```

And after that you have a official step-by-step tutorial here :
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

*P.S : Don't worry it's pretty easy and don't take long and you don't risk to lose your files (you can make a backup anyway if you want) and if you messed up with the partition table just run testdisk again and fix it*